# Sending image in correct format to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: json, image, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, image-uploading

I'm currently using the JSON API to send an image to GCS. However, when I send an image in base64, the image does not show up. Here is my request code

```
  fetch(gcloud_storage_url+`?uploadType=media&name=${name}`, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({image: imageBase64})
  }).then(resp => { console.log(resp) })
```

Not sure if my post body is in the wrong format.

Comment: You need to provide response, any error info, the url you used, etc.

Comment: I believe for uploadType=media, you should just send the raw image data, not base64-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload), when using JSON API to upload image to Cloud Storage where ‘uploadType=media’, make sure the media is less than 5 MB and it does not contain metadata. If you have bigger media file or metadata, use ‘multipart’ or ‘resumable’ for ‘uploadType’.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload#example_sending_a_simple_upload_request) is an example of the upload method. If not, as Oliver [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960626/sending-image-in-correct-format-to-google-cloud-storage#comments-49960626), please provide any error or response information.